# How to increase date by one month from fetched date from the database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to increase date by one month but,
current date is working , but my need is to increase date by one month ( dynamically )

I tried this from response bellow

```
 $regdate=$row2['created_date'];
 $onemonth = date($regdate,  strtotime("+1 month"));
```

**How to add $regdate variable to date function...?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$regdate = strtotime($row2['created_date']);
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 month",$regdate));
```

Comment: I tried before but it wont work for me   $regdate=2018-11-28     and what i am getting after run that code  is =1970-02-01

Comment: @darshan Please check now I have done few changes.

Comment: It is a easy way thank you @prashant

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$regdate=$row2['created_date'];
$date = new DateTime($regdate);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

$date->add($interval);
$onemonth = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but i want define variable instead of   2000-12-31 any suggestion ..?

Comment: @Darshan what do you mean ' i want define variable instead of 2000-12-31'? I changed the code snippet BTW

Comment: Yes i tried but it show as it is (not incremented )

Comment: DateTimeImmutable should have worked. May be I did something wrong. It works with DateTime() class.

Answer (score 1):

in my point of view ,  i think it will be perfect if you got the data edited from database before the php statements :

MYSQL level :

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD( yourDate, INTERVAL 1 month ) from your table .
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

added 1 month in given date

```
  $date = $row2['created_date'];
  $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month") );
  echo $date;
```

You can add the required time period as below:

```
Add day
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day") );

Multiple days
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +15 days") );

Add week
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week") );

Add month
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month") );
```

Comment: Its Working , this is what i am looking for thank you @manoj

Comment: @Darshan.. happy to help you, you can mark it as an accepted answer with an upvote :)